# React Router Dom v5 not redirecting in my website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a main website that is accessible to everyone. And I have another page that can only be seen once you press a button that would redirect you to said page.  I have already implemented my routes on my `App.js` and placed the , however when I click the button, it does not redirect me to the specified page.

**App.js:**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';
import Dropdown from './Components/Dropdown';
import Hero from './Components/Hero';
import AboutUs from './Components/AboutUs';
import OurProgram from './Components/OurProgram';
import Research from './Components/Research';
import Data from './Components/Data';
import Loan from './Components/Loan';
import ScrollToTop from './Components/ScrollToTop';
import Gov from './Components/Gov';


import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

{/* Backend of Toggle function */ }
function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsopen] = useState(false)

  const toggle = () => {
    setIsopen(!isOpen)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar toggle={toggle} />
      <Dropdown isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/">
          <Hero />
          <AboutUs />
          <OurProgram />
          <Research />
          <Loan />
          <Footer />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/Gov">
          <Gov />
        </Route>

      </Switch>



    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**link used:**

```js
<Link to="/Gov" className='bg-yellow-500 text-white font-bold p-5 mb-3  rounded-lg md:p-18 text-2xl '>Useful gov links</Link>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of your `Switch`, as it is defined, you will always be at the home page cause this `/` and this `/jfdf` both will match the first path. A solution could be changing the order like so:

```js
 <Switch>
    <Route path="/Gov">
      <Gov />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/">
      <Hero />
      <AboutUs />
      <OurProgram />
      <Research />
      <Loan />
      <Footer />
    </Route>      
 </Switch>
```

Or use the `exact` property, like so:

```js
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/">
    <Hero />
    <AboutUs />
    <OurProgram />
    <Research />
    <Loan />
    <Footer />
  </Route>
  <Route  path="/Gov">
    <Gov />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```